# How to create a group with a group ID in Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell

I would like to do the Windows equivalent of these Linux commands:

```
sudo groupadd -r -g 82 alpine-www-data
sudo usermod -a -G alpine-www-data $(id -un)
```

What I'm personally trying to achieve is explained in this question:

https://serverfault.com/questions/842789/docker4wordpress-fixing-permission-problems-for-windows

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please don't cross-post.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe I understand, however the question is independent - here I'm asking specifically about the powershell alternative of those Bash commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell to create a `alpine-www-data` group and add the `Administrator` account to it:

```
$Computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$User = "Administrator"
$GroupName = "alpine-www-data"

$ADSI = [ADSI]("WinNT://$Computer")
$Group = $ADSI.Create("Group", $GroupName)
$Group.SetInfo()

$Group.Add(("WinNT://$computer/$user"))
```

And the CMD version of it:

```
net localgroup alpine-www-data /add
net localgroup alpine-www-data Administrator /add
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to give this group specifically the GID of 82?

Comment: Windows groups don't have numeric IDs, so ... no.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe Thank you, then it is just what I was looking for.